# AutoMapper object to ICollection<object>

Tags: c#, automapper

I haven an class which is an id value type defined in one line. Like this:

```
public class PropertiesModel
{
    public decimal property1 { get; set; }
    public decimal property2 { get; set; }
    ...
    public decimal propertyz { get; set; }
}
```

and I want to map it to an array of Id Value as follows, creating simple a collection of this class:

```
public class IdValue
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

resulting value should be and object like:

```
IdValue[] exampleResult = new IdValue[] 
{
    new IdValue {
       Id = property1, // THe name of the first field in Property model
       Value = PropertiesModel.property1 // The actual value of the property 1 on the model
    },
    new IdValue {
       Id = property2, // THe name of the second field in Property model
       Value = PropertiesModel.property2 // The actual value of the property 2 on the model
    },
    ...
    new IdValue {
       Id = propertyz, // THe name of the z-field in Property model
       Value = PropertiesModel.propertyz // The actual value of the property z on the model
    }
}
```

I have been trying to do this with the AutoMapper as:

```
CreateMap<PropertiesModel, ICollection<IdValue>>()
    .ForMember(x => x,
        y => y.MapFrom(z => new IdValue
        {
            Id = "Property 1",
            Value = z.property1
         }))
    .ForMember(x => x,
        y => y.MapFrom(z => new IdValue
        {
            Id = "Property 2",
            Value = z.property2
         }))
     ...
    .ForMember(x => x,
        y => y.MapFrom(z => new IdValue
        {
            Id = "Property Z",
            Value = z.propertyz
         }))
```

But this is not working, is it possible to do the automapper this way? I'm sure I'm missing something in here. Have try read the documentation, but haven't found a similar example to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Are you trying to figure this out with AutoMapper specifically or are you open for another solution?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out for AutoMapper, thanks

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use `ConvertUsing`

```
CreateMap<PropertiesModel, ICollection<IdValue>>()
    .ConvertUsing(obj => obj.GetType()
                        .GetProperties()
                        .Select(prop => new IdValue
                          {
                              Id = prop.Name,
                              Value = (decimal)prop.GetValue(obj)
                          })
                        .ToArray());
```